# How can I extract screen from mobile device using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, extract, detect

I want to extract screen part from mobile device picture using python.
Can I get the 4 edges or points screen part (I don't know whether I can get screen with iphone notch style)

I think it seems possible using openCV, but I don't know how to adpat it.

If you can help, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

[I want to draw green box like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNsYM.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your image and what part you want to extract ?

Comment: @Ziri, I add an image. I want to draw the green box like this.

Comment: Use this code to extract the bounsing box https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html  but if your target image is rotated  use : minAreaRect instead . you'll get 4 corners .

Comment: when you get 4 point's   check here how to Crop an ROI with opencv https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/js_basic_ops_roi.html

Comment: Thanks, let me try and get back again. Oh, there also python code as well. Thanks.

Comment: Bounding box tutorial : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html                                    Roi crop example : docs.opencv.org/trunk/js_basic_ops_roi.html

Answer (score 1):

here is simple example of finding contours that may be useful for you:

```
image = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/img.jpg')

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

# find contours
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# sort by area and leave only 5 largest
nts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]  

screenCnt = None

# iterate over contours and find which satisfy some conditions
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True) # you could tune value of 0.02
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)

    if h >= 15 and len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break

# if found
if screenCnt is not None:
    # draw rect
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(screenCnt)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
    # or draw contour
    cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

red - approx rectangle
blue - contour